# error: Read is not a reg in this context

Tags: verilog

I am trying to create date\a memory using verilog but there is a error like below,

> error: Read is not a reg in this context.

my code is like this,what is the error?

```
module DataMemory(Read,Write,Address,memW,memR);
input memR,memW;
input[15:0] Address,Write;
output [15:0] Read;
reg [15:0]temR;
reg [15:0] DataMem[15:0];
integer i;

initial
    begin
        //set zero all initial value;
        for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1)
        begin
            DataMem[i] =16'd0;
        end
    end
always @(memW,memR)
begin
    if(memR == 1)
    begin
        temR[15:0]=DataMem[Address];
    end
    if(memW == 1)
    begin           
        DataMem[Address] = Write;
    end
    assign Read[15:0]=temR;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `assign` keyword when making procedural assignments.